# Vue 3 migration: how to keep plugin in options API?

Tags: vuejs2, plugins, vuejs3, migration

I am migrating some applications from Vue 2 to Vue 3. These applications use a lot of plugins of the following form:

```js
export default {
  install: (Vue, options) => {
    Vue.prototype.$myPlugin = new Vue({
      data () {
        return {
          aData: 123
        }
      },
      computed: {
        aComputed () {
          // ...
        }
      },
      methods: {
        aMethod () {
          // ...
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

In Vue 2 we then benefit from the data and computed reactivity (in addition to using the methods):

```js
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.$myPlugin.aData = 456
    const someConst = this.$myPlugin.aComputed
    this.$myPlugin.aMethod()
  }
}
```

In Vue 3, Vue is no longer a constructor -> I get the runtime error `Uncaught TypeError: Vue is not a constructor`. I cannot find a "new Vue" equivalent in Vue 3. **Is there a way to continue using options API in Vue 3 plugins?**

I am aware about the composition API. In a new Vue 3 project I would use the following syntax (or a more up-to-date provide/inject):

```js
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  install: (app, options) => {
    const aData = ref(123)

    const aComputed = computed(() => {
      // ...
    })
    
    function aMethod () {
      // ...
    }

    app.config.globalProperties.$myPlugin = {
      aData,
      aComputed,
      aMethod
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately in my migration context this would be a huge amount of work. I'm looking for a faster solution... if it exists!

Thanks :)